# Error al compilar con PyInstaller: error cargando la DLL de Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

Estoy compilando mi primer Aplicación GUI, estoy usando pyinstaller porque es el que conozco, me genera el archivo .exe

```
from tkcalendar import Calendar, DateEntry
from tkinter.ttk import * 
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import *
import datetime
import sqlite3
```

Luego cuando voy a ejecutar el archivo exe me aparece este error, por favor, me pueden decir a que se refiere o donde puedo yo buscar de que trata bel error o si hay otra manera de compilar mas efectiva.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el texto que genera el compilador, no se leerlo, no veo si aquí describe el error que tengo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco cualquier ayuda, saludos y gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Has instalado correctamente [pywin32-ctypes](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32-ctypes/)?, es una dependencia de PyInstaller en Windows.

Comment: Gracias por ayudarme, instale pywin32-ctypes y me sigue generando los 2 errores, también me genera 2 .exe uno en la carpeta  build y otro en la carpeta dist, pero cuando los ejecuto aparece el mismo mensaje como si no consiguiera esa librería.

Comment: prueba reinstalando PyInstaller

Comment: Gracias reinstale py installer usando las instrucción: pip install pyinstaller, y me sigue dando el mismo error.

Comment: Prueba a instalar pywin32 directamente mediante los binarios :https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/releases/tag/b227. Asegurate de elegir la versión adecuada para tu instaalación de Python (3.8, 3.7, etc y la arquitectura, 32 / 64 bits)

Comment: Gracias @FJSevilla, he instalado el pywin32 directamente mediante el link, uso Python 3.8.1 (tags/v3.8.1:1b293b6, Dec 18 2019, 22:39:24) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32 en AMD 64Bits, instale el pywin32 para 32bit siguiendo la instrucción porque es la versión de Python que instale. pero me sigue generando el error, he modificado la pregunta y imprimí las pantallas que genera el pyinstaller a ver si allí se puede percibir el problema, agradezco cualquier orientación, saludos y gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Te recomiendo que uses p2exe, es una utiletaria de python que te permite generar ejecutables a tu antojo, es decir, en un script defines las librerías que usaras y queda tu ejecutable. te dejo un link que puede ayudarte.

El error que muestras es generado por que le faltan dependencias a tu ejecutable para que pueda ser ejecutado con éxito.

https://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial#Step2

Comment: Muchas gracias, Xavier Angeles,  lo he intentado y me genera error, no termina de compilar, tendras un ejemplo setup.py para guiarme?

Comment: Si, dame oportunidad de buscarlo y te lo paso

Comment: mucha gracias se lo agradeceria

Comment: @JuancarlosPantoja aunque py2exe como propone Xaveir es otra opción y no pierdes nada por provar, hay que tener en cuenta que  está en realidad sin mantenimiento desde 2017 y su última versión en PyPi es de 2014... Por lo que el soporte para versiones actuales de Python puede tener problemas, pyinstaller, cxfreezer, py2app (OS X) o el más exótico pyOxidizer dentro de los freezers o Nuitka (compilación) son proyectos mantenidos actualmente.